# Get selected item in SharePoint list

Tags: list, web-part

I have a SharePoint list and a webpart with a button. Following is the case.

1. User selects multiple items from the list.
2. When user clicks on the button of the webpart, I would like to know the detail of the selected items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [SP.ListOperation.Selection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409526(v=office.14).aspx) class getSelectedItems() method to get the selected list items. You will get the IDs of the selected list items based on which you can do the further processing.

[Here](http://tomaszrabinski.pl/wordpress/2012/02/25/get-selected-list-items-sharepoint-2010/) is a good post. You might also want to consider going through [this](http://arsalkhatri.wordpress.com/2012/12/01/sharepoint-2010-get-selected-items-from-list-view-in-visual-web-part/) post.

Answer (score 1):

[SP.ListOperation.Selection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408826(v=office.14).aspx) provides static methods for *selecting lists or list items*.

[SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409526%28v=office.14%29.aspx) returns the list of items being selected. Selected list item contains the following properties:

- `id` - list item id
- `fsObjType` - file system object type

The following example demonstrates how  to retrieve selected list items:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList(); //get selected list Id
var selectedItemIds = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context); //get selected items
for (idx in selectedItemIds)
{
    var itemId = (parseInt(selectedItemIds[idx].id));
    var isListItem = (selectedItemIds[idx].fsObjType == "0");
    //..
}
```

The next example demonstrates how to retrieve selected [SP.ListItem object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410681(v=office.14).aspx) collection:

```
function getSelectedItems()
{
    var dfd = $.Deferred(function () {
       var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
       var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList(); //get selected list Id
       var selectedItemIds = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context); //get selected objects

       var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
       var listItems = [];
       for (idx in selectedItemIds)
       {
          var item = list.getItemById(parseInt(selectedItemIds[idx].id));
          listItems.push(item);
          context.load(item);
       }
       context.executeQueryAsync(
         function() {
            dfd.resolve(listItems);
         },
         function (sender, args) {
               dfd.reject(args.get_message());
         }
       ); 
    });
    return dfd.promise();   
}
```

Usage

```
getSelectedItems().then(function(items){
  for (var i =0 ; i < items.length;i++)
  {
   var fileUrl = items[i].get_item('FileRef');
   console.log(fileUrl);
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to implement it on the server side using C#?