# Get selected list items from Sharepoint Web Part

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online, javascript

I am making a web part that will be added to a list page, and I need to access the selected items in the list. I am trying to do this using the following method (mentioned here: [Get selected item in SharePoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114484/get-selected-item-in-sharepoint-list)):

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList(); //get selected list Id
var selectedItemIds = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context); //get selected items
```

I initially included this code as part of a custom view, which worked well, however when running this as part of a web part I get the following error after calling the getSelectedList function:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: GetCurrentCtx is not defined

I am assuming this change has to with the fact that the Web Part is running in an IFrame, but I am stuck as to how to get around this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

After adding core.js I now get the following error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: IsNullOrUndefined is not defined

These are all the js files I am including :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/core.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs since `GetCurrentCtx` function is a part of `core.js` SharePoint   library, it is intended for getting context info of [XLV web part](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.xsltlistviewwebpart) (`ContextInfo` object), so:

- `core.js` library have to be loaded first
- it could be executed *only* in the SharePoint page that contains the instance of XLV web part since `ContextInfo` object is generated when the XLV web part is rendered on page

Comment: Thanks for the response. I included core.js, but I now get "IsNullOrUndefined is not defined" when loading the page. Any ideas?